# How to delete in a B-Tree when all nodes are singletons

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

I'm working though the B-Tree example given on the ever wonderful wikipedia [on this page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) (I'm using wikipedia, because Stackoverflow tells me to... [How do you remove an element from a b-tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185920/how-do-you-remove-an-element-from-a-b-tree)

I'm happy with the construction of this tree.

[image]

..and I find the algorithm elegant.

My issue is that the descriptions on Wikipedia for deleting a node appear to be missing a case. The three cases given for 're-balancing after deletion' are:

- If the deficient node's right sibling exists and has more than the minimum number of elements, then rotate left
- Otherwise, if the deficient node's left sibling exists and has more than the minimum number of elements, then rotate right
- Otherwise, if both immediate siblings have only the minimum number of elements, then merge with a sibling sandwiching their separator taken off from their parent.

None of which turn out to be helpful if the deficient node has *no* siblings (for example in the tree above, delete '1', '3' is now deficient and has no siblings).

My question is, what is the case/cases that are missing (presuming I've understood correctly), and what *should* the Wikipedia page say?

Answer (score 2):

> for example in the tree above, delete '1', '2' is now deficient and has no siblings

Yes, it has a sibling: The node (6,_). If you have *no* siblings, you are the root.

So in this case, we apply option 3 and end up with a two-level tree.

Comment: Whoops - I typed '2', rather than '3' but that might have given the answer - are you saying that leaf nodes are never deficient - just internal nodes? I can get behind that...

Comment: @Joe You can simply remove empty leaf nodes, yes. The parent might get deficient though, in which case you need to rebalance